# Windowns Phone 8 link to setting

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can I make link into setting in phone from my application? For example like a link to other page (NavigateTo)?
I would like to make buttun, witch navigate you to mobile setting....

thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [link](http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/11/12/opening-settings-screen-using-launch-uri-in-windows-phone/). You can do that by invoking `LaunchUriAsync` method passing one of available settings Uri as parameter :

```
public async void OpenSettings(string settingsName)
{
    var op = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(settingsName));
}
```

Available Uri :

```
1. ms-settings-airplanemode: .
2. ms-settings-bluetooth:
3. ms-settings-cellular:
4. ms-settings-emailandaccounts:
5. ms-settings-location:
6. ms-settings-power:
7. ms-settings-screenrotation:
8. ms-settings-wifi:
```

Comment: [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Content is about the same as link in the answer.